# getting " Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD exception" while adding apche cxf-bundle as dependency in gradle

Tags: java, build.gradle, wsdl2java

Trying to add an apache-cxf bundle in my application.But getting the following error while running the application
    Failed to instantiate 
 [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

which is caused by 
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD

Tried to add the following properties in the task

```
wsdl2java {
 System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
 System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalDTD','all')
 generatedWsdlDir = file("src/main/generated-sources/")  // target directory for generated source code
 wsdlsToGenerate = [   //  2d-array of wsdls and cxf-parameters
                      ['src/main/resources/xsd/wsdl/***.wsdl'],
]
```

}

```
added the dependency as 
compile group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-bundle', version: '2.4.2'
```

getting the following error

```
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.mapping.PayloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping]: Factory method 'payloadRootAnnotationMethodEndpointMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not supported: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/property/accessExternalDTD
    at org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl.setAttribute(TransformerFactoryImpl.java:576) ~[xalan-2.7.1.jar:?]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While checking the dependency tree, Seeing multiple version of Xalan.Which make the dependency conflict. Error is resolved by adding the following line

```
 compile (group: 'org.apache.cxf', name: 'cxf-bundle', version: '2.4.2')  {    
 exclude module: 'xalan'
}
```